# Parallel battery charging UPS

Tags: power-supply, battery, power, ps4

Just bought new ips for 25 dollars and have bought 3 batteries 12v 9ah each.

What i did is the following

1. Opened the UPS and connected positive end of the battry to a wire that is connected to a screw (called + screw)

   2. Connected negative end of the internal ups to another screw (- screw)
   3. I have external box that contains 2 same batteries 12v 9ah
   4. Connected all positves of external battery to the positve screw
   5. Connected all negatives of the external batteries to the negative screw of the ups.

Now what happens... when i plug the power cord and ups is on, with electrical screw driver, i can't see power through the positve screw nor the positive ends on all two external battries. This happens when charging... 
Does this mean that the external batteries are not being charged?

When I unplug the ups for testing, backup power keeps my lamp on and when i check the electricity via electrical screw I can see there's current on the positives and negatives of the external batteries as well as on the positive and negative screws.

Please let me know if this is expected behavior or there's something wrong.

Sample photo of the setup
https://ibb.co/rbchtdk

Video showing the issue if any 
https://streamable.com/4c8aio

My ups details FSUPS850VA 
850va

Comment: What do you mean by "with electrical screw driver, i can't see power through the positve screw nor the positive ends on all two external battries?" BTW, add fuses in each positive battery wire, for safety!!

Comment: Dear pls gave a look at the provided video. Thank for your valuable reply

Comment: A test light for mains voltage will not work with 12 V DC. If you want to test something like your setup, use a proper multimeter. Though I seriously doubt this will work as expected either way.

Comment: @Daniel thanks for your reply. What do you mean by this won't work as expected? The setup or the multimeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You seem to know just enough about electricity to be dangerous. Please stop, and get someone more knowledgeable to comprehensively sanity-check your idea. Or just buy a battery charger from a car supply store.**

That "electrical screw driver" seems to include a voltage tester, probably one designed for the mains voltage of your country (probably 110 volts or more).

Voltage is not an absolute value: it is always relative to some other reference point. In normal houses, the "zero volts" reference level is "ground", or more specifically, either a dedicated grounding electrode stuck into the ground, or in some countries, it is allowed to use bare metal water pipes going through the ground as an electrical grounding/earthing point.

There is also the concept of *an electrical circuit.* When using electricity for power, you'll need two conductors: one for electric current to travel from the power source to whatever you need powered, and another for the current to return to the source. With just one point of contact, you may get a zap of static electricity (which may be dangerous in itself, if the amount of electric charge is large enough), but to get "properly electrocuted", you would need two points of contact, so that you'll become part of an electrical circuit with enough power to harm you.

With power lines, earth/ground is often used as the return route, to save on the amount of copper/aluminium required for the wires. This makes mains electricity always dangerous: if you are not completely elecrically insulated from the ground and touch a mains wire, a circuit will form between the power plant, mains wire, you, and the ground, and you will get shocked in a continuous manner until a fuse blows, a breaker trips, or you manage to disconnect your self from the circuit.

In the case of "electrical screw driver", the tip of the screwdriver provides one contact point... and the other contact is through **you**. The tester includes a resistor that is supposed to limit the electric current through the screwdriver to a harmless level. But you should understand that the tester in the screwdriver is essentially just a "would this shock me if I touched it unprotected?" kind of tester, designed for your standard mains voltage level.

Batteries like the ones you're planning to charge, on the other hand, use a much lower voltage, often about 6 or 12 volts. The voltage is determined by the number of individual cells in the battery and the type of electrochemical reaction the battery is based on.

When the UPS is plugged in, its internal workings are connected to the building's ground/earth reference through the ground/earth wire in the power cord, and so the UPS's "zero volts" reference point will be the same as the building's.

When you touch any point of the charging circuit with the screwdriver, there is just one point of contact into the charging circuit, so there will be no complete circuit through the screwdriver+you back into the charging circuit. And even if you grabbed the bare opposite-polarity charging wire in your other hand, the voltage for charging the batteries would probably be too low to light up the tester designed for mains voltage.

But what happens when you unplug the UPS? Now the UPS is still trying to produce mains voltage, but it will have no connection to the building ground/earth. Effectively, its internal workings are no longer firmly anchored to the building's zero-volts reference level, and may "drift".

When the UPS is producing mains-equivalent power without a ground connection "anchor", its internal workings will "float" at a voltage level that is typically half of your mains voltage. And that includes the charging circuit in its entirety: as the batteries are also insulated from the building ground/earth, the negative half of the charging circuit might be at the level of (half of your mains voltage) relative to the house, and the positive half will be at (half of your mains voltage + 12 volts).

For the battery, the only thing that matters is that the difference between the positive and negative contacts matches the voltage the battery's designed for. But for people around your contraption, it will be hard to predict which two things could give you a half-mains-voltage zap when touched at the same time.

But adding extra batteries in parallel to the UPS's built-in one may overload the UPS's charging circuit.

If you want to charge batteries, you should go to an automobile supply shop and buy a regular battery charger that can provide the correct voltage. They would be easier to use, and usually would have charging circuits that can adapt to different battery capacities: the one in the UPS may be optimized to the exact capacity of the UPS's battery and may get easily overloaded.